# Shared Volume of Overlapping 3D Cubes/Rectangles

Tags: 3d, volume, solid-geometry, collision-detection

Good afternoon,

I have been looking for an approach to figure out the volume where two cubes/rectangles overlap, meaning, I know when they do, I just don't know the coordinates of the volume in which they do.

Would someone be able to provide and answer or help?

Comment: Are these rectangles/cubes aligned with the coordinate axes?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, didnt' get the reply notification. They can have any rotation in a 3D environment